# How to calculate area under a normal distribution in Java?

Tags: java, math

I am trying to calculate the area under the curve for a normal distribution. Normally, I can refer to a calculator or z table. But, how would I code this? I have the values of z, mu, sigma and the bounds. I saw multiple codes online, but none of them explain the logic behind it. Rather than using an external method, I would like to learn how this works and then write a code for it.

It would be a great help, if someone can provide an algorithm to how to calculate the area under curve using z, mu, sigma and the bounds, without any complex details.

Thanks

Comment: The logic behind this is not a programming related issue but rather is in the math domain and can be found from the usual online sources, such as Google, Wikipedia, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific program issue but rather the logic behind a math algorithm.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to open a math book and look for "calculus". normal distribution is e ^ (- x ^ 2) right?

Comment: I think "area under the curve of a normal distribution" = "cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution"? If so, you can compute it from the complementary error function, `erfc()`, like so: `standard_normal_cdf(x) = 0.5*erfc(-sqrt(0.5)*x); normal_cdf (x,mu,sigma) = standard_normal_cdf ((x-mu)/sigma);` How to import `erfc()` is shown in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221406/use-of-erfc-function-commons-apache-org-library)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know the maths, but how to perform intergral in java? I mean is there any other way other than the integral or how to do integral without knowing y.

Comment: @learningJava You don't need to integrate. There is a function called the error function that is closely related to the CDF of the standard normal distribution. and the latter can be computed from the former. The error functions is provided in C/C++ via `erf()` and `erfc()` but Java seems to be missing these functions in its math library. An implementation is available from Apache however as I pointed out above.

Comment: @njuffa that's not _entirely_ true. The error function is by definition an integral. It's just nice to not have to worry about integrals and let a library do it for you :)

Comment: @Michael Goldstein I am not sure I understand your point. I did not state that the CDF of the normal distribution is not an integral. I said *we* do not need to integrate because there is a commonly used and readily available function (also an integral :-) from which it can be computed.

Comment: @njuffa there really was no point except to emphasize that it's not as simple as multiplying a couple things together or the exponentiation of something. You are correct in saying that for anything practical, a library for the error function should be used, like the one in Apache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it the same way you would in any other language!

The normal distribution is defined to have a probability as follows:

[image]

What you need to do is integrate that. First, make that probability distribution into a method. We can simplify it by just using mu = 0 and sigma = 1.

```
/** 
 * Returns the height of the normal distribution at the specified z-score
 */
double getNormalProbabilityAtZ(double z) {
    return Math.exp(-Math.pow(z, 2) / 2) / Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI);
}
```

Next, we need a method to integrate. The idea is we divide it into a bunch of tiny parts, get the y value at each of those parts, and then multiply by the width of our rectangles. [Here's more reading on Riemann Sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html) in case you're unfamiliar.

```
/**
  * Returns the area under the normal curve between the z-scores z1 and z2
  */
double getAreaUnderNormalCurve(double z1, double z2) {
    double area = 0.0;
    final int rectangles = 100000; // more rectangles = more precise, less rectangles = quicker execution
    final double width = (z2 - z1) / rectangles;
    for(int i = 0; i < rectangles; i++)
        area += width * getNormalProbabilityAtZ(width * i + z1);
    return area;
}
```

There you have it!

If you need to find the area under the normal distribution from let's say a z-score of 1 to infinity, just do something like 1 to 5 as in `getAreaUnderNormalCurve(1, 5)`. Why? Because After `z=3`, the area under the bell curve is very small. After `z=5`, it's negligible to the point that it's not even worth integrating over.

Disclaimer: if you need the most speed and precision, you shouldn't implement this yourself. Use a library already in existence such as the [Apache Commons Error Function](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Erf.html#erf%28double%29). You can get the Normal Cumulative Distribution from the Error Function by the following relationship `normalCdf(x) = 1/2 + 1/2 * erf(x / sqrt(2))`

Happy coding OP, if that still doesn't make sense please comment and I'd be happy to edit my answer.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. There are many well-tested algorithms in easily found libraries, as well as simple series expansions, continues fractions, etc. Numerical integration is a last-ditch method to use when you can't come up with something more efficient.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's less than practical to do this yourself. Certainly when a library is available, use it. I think OP has made it pretty clear though that he is interested in understanding the Math behind and using it for more academic purposes than practical purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your descriptive answer, but the problem with Riemann sums is that, it requires the height/y. I don't have that. I just have x, sigma and mean. Is there any other way, i can solve it without y

Comment: @learningJava you use the probability distribution to get the height, y. The method I included above, `getNormalProbabilityAtX`, will compute the "height" at a given z-score. To get a z-score from x, sigma, and mu, do `z = (x - mu) / sigma`

Comment: Worst. idea. ever. Don't approximate an intergral, when you can calculate it.

Comment: @EvanDark There is no closed form for the integral of the normal distribution... every calculation of the error function is an approximation. They're almost certainly better approximations than the one you see here. I provided this for help with understanding the math behind the calculation.

Comment: Approximating with it's Taylor series has an error as small as O(n^4) even if you only use a cubic polynomial. Approximating the area with rectangles has an error of O(n), and generally only used if the function to approximate isn't known.

Comment: @EvanDark I don't disagree. However, throwing code for the taylor series at OP when he probably already found that code (see question) doesn't help him or her understand the math behind. I provided the reimann sum method not because it's the most accurate but because it's very intuitive that the value you need is the integral of the normal distribution. If it makes you feel better, I have updated the question to note that if accuracy and speed is of priority, the Apache Commons Math lib should be used (which uses the Taylor series method to calculate the error function)

Comment: @MichaelGoldstein: My main problem was, that you presented the code as "solution". It's a good way to explain how the Riemann Summs work, but it's not a good code. even just applying an 1/2 weight to both ends improves the estimation quite a bit (Using trapezoids, rather than rectangles).

Comment: @EvanDark My apologies then, that wasn't my intention. And there's really no need to use trapezoids since neither is a good approximation; the idea is just to show it is an integral. Anyhow, this is getting to be a little too extended of a conversation so let's leave it at this. If you feel my question is still not presented well please edit it.

Comment: You would want to compute the standard normal CDF via `erfc()` rather than `erf()` to avoid issues with rapidly increasing relative error in the left tail: `standard_normal_cdf(x) = 0.5*erfc(-sqrt(0.5)*x)`.